# Python saving xml from webservice

Tags: python

I'm using a webservice to get a certain xml file from it. It works fine with urllib2 I get the xml as fileobject. So I want to know what would be the fastest way to store that somewhere in memory or not even store just parse it.

I tried iterparse on that object and it takes too long unless I save it first in file, then iterparse takes much less time.

So now I'm using this code to store it locally first and then do with that file what I want, and I would like to know is there a fastest way of doing it, fastest way of storing files.

```
url = "webservice"
s = urllib2.urlopen(url)

file = open("export.xml",'wb+')
for line in s:
    file.write(line)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to write line-by-line. Just write the whole thing in one go:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = "webservice"
>>> s = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> contents = s.read()
>>> file = open("export.xml", 'w')
>>> file.write(contents)
>>> file.close()
```

Comment: Yes I can, but the speed is actually the same, and I'm after the speed in this case

Comment: While there might be moderately faster techniques, the speed constraints here are probably network- and disk-based.

Comment: If you get an error `write() argument must be str, not bytes`, use `wb` instead of `w`for the `open` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a string:

```
content = s.read()
```

or a StringIO if you need file-like interface

```
content = cStringIO.StringIO()
content.write(s.read)
```